# Azure with API for WPF and javascript

Tags: php, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I want to create following project :

1. Server application hosted on Azure - it connects to databse via Entity framework and gives and API for anyone who want to connect (but with account stored in SQL database)
2. WPF application - it consumes server methods, objects etc.
3. Web app (php & javascript) - also consumes server methods and object etc.

**IMPORTANT** : I have only azure student's subscription and I want to hold onto it - buying anything else is out of the question unless it has strong argumentation.

I figured that to do this I have to create REST Web API because I have no other choice to connect to server than via HTTPWebRequest (because I want to have the same API for WPF nad web app).

My question is : **does better solution exists?**

I think I can create different API's for desktop client than web app but I have no idea how to do that. Whould you be so kindly to show me other way?

Why dont I want to have this solution? 
Reason is simple. For big databases and slow internet connection it would take ages to download whole data in few seconds. As far as my knowledge goes there is no lazy loading in REST thus my WPF application's thread reponsible for downloading database would freeze for a big period of time.

If my question is too broad please leave a comment before you put up a flag.
Also, any tips regarding my project design are well appreciated.

Comment: No lazy-loading in REST, no - usually you would implement this in the form of rate limiting (leaky bucket algorithm) split up among subsequent requests using an offset and resource limit.  This breaks big resource requests up into multiple http requests which allows your server a break and a chance to throttle/load balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Different APIs for Desktop and Web**: this can be done easily enough.  Assume you have a class library to contain your business logic (domain stuff).  Create a web api project that makes use of it, then create yet another web api project separately that also makes use of the core models.  When you deploy, deploy each separately to a different domain/subdomain (I'm unsure if you'll require further Azure resources for this, but consider `api.desktop.myapp.com` and `api.web.myapp.com`... no real technical reason why you can't do it that way, though for architecture reasons I'd avoid it (it's really coming close to if not definitely is duplication of code).

**Same API for Desktop and Web**: you stated that you thought you'd have to do this differently for the desktop and web, specifically because of the resource usage on the server.  I disagree here, and think you should implement some standardized rate limiting into your API.  Typically this is done by allowing only X amount of resources to be returned in a single call.  If the initial request asks for more than X limit, an offset/nextID is returned by the API, and the client submits a new request noting that offset/nextID.  This means you have subsequent calls from the client to get everything it needs, but gives your server a chance to handle it in smaller chunks (e.g., check for rate limits, throttling, load balancing, etc).  See the *leaky bucket algorithm* for an implementation that I prefer, myself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket)

Comment: IF you do want to use the same API for Desktop and Web and your application is just consuming SQL resources - Azure Mobile Apps provides a common OData v3 resource linked to a SQL Azure backend - both these items can be implemented in Azure for free (Azure App Service + SQL Azure both have an F-Free pricing plan available).  Azure Mobile Apps also provides client SDKs - Web / JavaScript, C# / .NET for UWP desktop applications and - if you go into the mobile world as well as desktop and web - plugins for iOS, Android, Xamarin, Windows Phone and Apache Cordova.

Comment: Thank you jdl134679 I will follow your advice and create API for both WPF and Web.
@AdrianHall I will try it, thanks!